# How to find the most related publications for a batch?

Tags: literature-search

On Google Scholar, I can explore the related articles or books individually - clicking on the "related articles" gives you the related articles for that specific publication.

How will I find the most related publications for a batch of articles/books?

Comment: I'm not aware of any service that lets you do that. It seems like a nontrivial research question.

Comment: Do you just want for each article in the list those articles most related to it (in which case it shouldn't be too hard to write a script utilizing Google Scholar for it), or do you want the articles most related to the collection of articles in your list? The latter indeed sounds difficult even to define!

Comment: @Arno Definitely the latter. Let's say there is an article `A` in my library. When I click on "related articles" button, let's say, there is an article `X` on the second page of related articles. When I click on the article `B` in my library, let's assume, `X` pops up on the third page. Continuing on the articles in my library, `X` reoccurs on several occasions, on either first or second, or third page. So, is there any way that such system will tell me that "dude, `X` kind of important! I can see it's related to all of your articles somehow. Better check that out!"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for might be possible by writing your own program (e.g. in Python) to access the Google Scholar API.  In fact it would make a good assignment for a Python programming / Text processing class. But unless you are a programmer with extra time on your hands, you shouldn't attempt it.

For what it's worth, I almost never use "related articles" feature of Google Scholar.  The few times I did use it, there wasn't always such a close relationship, and it certainly didn't bring up the articles that *I* saw as most related.

I don't think there's any substitute for reading the papers, at least the important ones, to find the most salient related papers.  I do this both through direct citations and also by finding key terms that I use for new Google Scholar searches.